# Counting active profiles in Paypal recurring payments via API

Tags: python, paypal

I want is for my python script to log into my Paypal account and check how many active profiles there are in my recurring payments section.

I can't find any API that would help me, TransactionSearch API isn't quite what I want - I don't want transactions, only active profiles

The only idea I have is to somehow detect every subscription and cancelation "on fly" and update a counter in the database. Although it seems... impure :)

Comment: If you include some code as to what you've tried, it is much easier to help you.

Comment: I have no code, because I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: the problem is that Gricha cannot find any API to use, so there is no code

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do (or would need to do) is record the profile ID's of every profile. So as a user signs up, you keep track of the profile ID. Then you can use [GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getrecurringpaymentsprofiledetails-api-operation-nvp) API to figure out if its active or not.